# Why does random.sample used with multiprocessing.Pool deadlock sometimes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

When I run the following snippet, sometimes it deadlocks and won't finish but sometimes it does. Why is this the case? I'm running Python 3.8 on Ubuntu 16.04 (4.4.0-173-generic).

```
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from random import sample

pool = Pool(4)
result = pool.map(partial(sample, range(10)), range(10))
```

The same happens when I create a fresh `random.Random` instance for every function call:

```
def sample(data, k):
    rand = random.Random()
    return rand.sample(data, k)
```

In case it hangs and I send SIGINT I get the following traceback, however I can't make sense of it:

```
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/util.py", line 277, in _run_finalizers
Process ForkPoolWorker-2:
Process ForkPoolWorker-1:
Process ForkPoolWorker-3:
    finalizer()
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/util.py", line 201, in __call__
    res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 689, in _terminate_pool
    cls._help_stuff_finish(inqueue, task_handler, len(pool))
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 674, in _help_stuff_finish
    inqueue._rlock.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
    task = get()
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
    task = get()
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 355, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 355, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
    task = get()
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 356, in get
    res = self._reader.recv_bytes()
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 216, in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 414, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 379, in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)
KeyboardInterrupt
Process ForkPoolWorker-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
    task = get()
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 355, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "[...]/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Shared resources need to be protected from being accessed by a second thread (process) when already engaged by another.  If you have a thread lock implemented, make sure you unlock when done with the shared resource.

Comment: @ryyker Could you provide more details? What resources are being shared, especially when creating a fresh `random.Random` instance every function call?

Comment: Hmm, this seems like a Python 3.8 bug to me. I can reproduce the hang on 3.8.2, but not 3.7.3.

Comment: I do not have python, or Linux with me so cannot comment too much, but does `inqueue._rlock.acquire()` need to be paired with a companion call to release the lock?  When I see a `lock` it makes me think it is there to protect something, or prevent access to something.  Unless that something is released from a lock when other processes need to access it, things will begin to stack up.  If that happens too long problems may appear.

Comment: ... However, @dano could be right, there is this [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue29759) report.

Comment: Indeed it seems to be an [open bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue38501) in Python 3.8. Actually it doesn't have to do with random.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [open bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue38501) in Python 3.8. It is not related to `random`, the reason is the cleanup of worker processes seems to be done incorrectly. For example the following deadlocks as well:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

def test(x):
    return 'test'

pool = Pool(4)
result = pool.map(test, range(10))
```

A solution is to either call `pool.close()` manually after the `map` returned or to use the pool object as a context manager:

```
with Pool(4) as pool:
    result = pool.map(test, range(10))
```